# How to use AngularJs ui-view and ng-view together in a single project

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a project where if i click on any link the view should change but the link should not change which i can achieve by using angular ui-route by state change. Also if i enter any view name in url that should also work, this can by achieve by using view-route.

In simple term if my url is **abc.com/home**  then the link should not change even if the view change lets say i go to contact, then also the link should be **abc.com/home**. But if i type **abc.com/contact** ,then i should be redirect to contact page.

I am not able to achieve this as i think that its two different routing mechanism.

Kindly help me on this, as to how we can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you simply need to show different content. Forget about URLs, simply change content after clicking certain buttons. You can display different pages with `ng-switch`, where your sub-pages will appear under `ng-switch-when="home_main"`. You should probably try to use `ng-include` to load your partials within those sections

Comment: Hi @AlekseySolovey, thanks for the ans. the ng-switch-when really helped.

Answer (score 1):

UI-Router official documentation tells one thing about that:

> **Issue: Problems when using ng-view alongside ui-view**
>
> Don't do that. You can use some thing like ng-include to assemble your page.

[Source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-problems-when-using-ng-view-alongside-ui-view)

Comment: This isn't really a helpful answer, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.